# how to solve negative samples generated in MLSMOTE

Tags: python

I'm working on a multi-label classification problem with an imbalanced dataset, so I'm trying to use MLSMOTE to solve the problem (multi-label synthetic minority over-sampling). Negative samples are created after using MLSMOTE. When i try to fit my model, i get an error message. Please guide me in finding a solution!!

```
binary_rel_clf = BinaryRelevance(MultinomialNB())

binary_rel_clf.fit(X_res,y_res)
```

when i run the above two line of code i got the error message stated below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-168-d57dddac20a5> in <module>
      1 binary_rel_clf = BinaryRelevance(MultinomialNB())
----> 2 binary_rel_clf.fit(X_res,y_res)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skmultilearn\problem_transform\br.py in fit(self, X, y)
    160                 y_subset = np.ravel(y_subset.toarray())
    161             classifier.fit(self._ensure_input_format(
--> 162                 X), self._ensure_output_format(y_subset))
    163             self.classifiers_.append(classifier)
    164 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    636 
    637         self._init_counters(n_effective_classes, n_features)
--> 638         self._count(X, Y)
    639         alpha = self._check_alpha()
    640         self._update_feature_log_prob(alpha)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py in _count(self, X, Y)
    769     def _count(self, X, Y):
    770         """Count and smooth feature occurrences."""
--> 771         check_non_negative(X, "MultinomialNB (input X)")
    772         self.feature_count_ += safe_sparse_dot(Y.T, X)
    773         self.class_count_ += Y.sum(axis=0)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_non_negative(X, whom)
   1123 
   1124     if X_min < 0:
-> 1125         raise ValueError("Negative values in data passed to %s" % whom)
   1126 
   1127 

ValueError: Negative values in data passed to MultinomialNB (input X)
```

Comment: Hello, could you please provide some code, what you tried, what error you get and so on? With current state of your question, it is absolutely impossible to help you.

Comment: ok thank you! i am already edited my question